# (SQL + Hibernate) Count records from 12 months ago

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

somebody can help me to find a way to get an `Array` that contains the **count** of  record by months using a `<date_field>` . I need to count every record from 12 months ago and if does not exist record then put **zero** into the Array.

This is my base code in java + hibernate:

```
public Integer[] getViewsPerMonths() {
    Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("");
    Integer[] viewsPerMonths = (Integer[])query.list().toArray();
    return viewsPerMonths;
}
```

Table example:

```
Id      |        View_Date     |

  1              01-01-2014
  2              02-01-2014
  3              03-01-2014
  4              03-01-2014
```

Desired result:

```
  Count  |    Month
   1           1
   1           2
   2           3
```

I'm using MySQL

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

For getting count in general the code would look like this:

```
CriteriaQuery<Long> countQuery = queryBuilder.createQuery(Long.class);
countQuery.select(criteriaBuilder.count(countQuery.from(clas)));
countQuery.where(condition);
count = entityManger.createQuery(countQuery).getSingleResult();
```

"condition" here would be your Predicate object. Something like:

```
condition = criteriaBuilder.between(v, x, y)
```

More info here: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html#between%28javax.persistence.criteria.Expression,%20javax.persistence.criteria.Expression,%20javax.persistence.criteria.Expression%29